# Is it possible to execute a task from within doLast?

Tags: gradle

I have the following:

```
task copyToLib(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.runtime
    into "$buildDir/output/lib"
    doLast { copyOpcThirdParty() } // this doesnt get executed
}

task copyOpcThirdParty(type: Copy) {
    from "$projectDir/libs/opc/thirdparty"
    into "$buildDir/output/lib/thirdparty/"
}
```

How can I call `copyOpcThirdParty` from `copyToLib.doLast`?

I tried `.execute()`, `tasks.copyOpcThirdParty`, etc, nothing worked..

Is it unsupported?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Gradle tasks are not executed directly. Instead you can register dependencies and Gradle then decides which tasks to execute in which order to achieve the execution of the tasks you specified (generally via command line). In older versions of Gradle you can call `execute()` directly on a task, but it should never be used.

When executing the tasks, the execution of one task must always be completely finished until another task can be executed. The execution of a task always covers running all `doFirst` closures, all internal task actions and all `doLast` closures.

For your specific example you can use the `finalizedBy` method. It tells Gradle that whenever a specific task runs, at some point after that another specific task also has to run:

```
copyToLib.finalizedBy copyOpcThirdParty
```